# Django Celery results set task id to something human readable?

Tags: python, django-celery, celery-task, celerybeat

After many days I have a working celery and celery beat task list, and the results are stored using django_celery_results. However when I look at the table record, it hasn't got any useful information in there.

is it possible to set the task id to something human readable?

[image: results]

one example would be using the demo task, it returns the no, but an unreadable task id

tasks.py

```
@app.task
def test(a,b):
    return a + b
```

scheduler in app.settings

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'test_task': {
        'task': 'home.tasks.test',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/1'),
    },
```

Answer (score 6):

The easy answer is No. The `task_id` attribute is generated automatically. If you follow the code backwards the core function that generates ID's is in [`kombu.utils.uuid.uuid(..)`](https://github.com/celery/kombu/blob/master/kombu/utils/uuid.py), which interestingly is just a thin wrapper around the builtin [`uuid.uuid4(..)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid4).

However, if you look at the function signature:

```
def uuid(_uuid=uuid4):
    """Generate unique id in UUID4 format.
    See Also:
        For now this is provided by :func:`uuid.uuid4`.
    """
    return str(_uuid())
```

..it appears like it would be possible to supply your own function that **generates** the ID, and as long as they're unique they should work. Fundamentally you'd have to patch: `celery.__init__.uuid`, `celery.utils.__init__.uuid`, and `celery.utils.__init__.gen_unique_id`.

I don't think that you'd be able to apply worthwhile names since this function is called with no parameters to simply return something unique.

**BUT**

If you look at [`Task.apply`](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/2f422c52bdd3dece65f05c1e7015b335e8bd0175/celery/app/task.py#L695-L698) and [`Task.apply_async`](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/2f422c52bdd3dece65f05c1e7015b335e8bd0175/celery/app/task.py#L418-L419) there's an undocumented parameter `task_id`!

This would allow you to manually specify the `task_id` *before* the Task is called/created, and as long as they're globally unique you'll still get all of the reporting and metrics. Unfortunately I don't see any easy way to change the `task_id` from a Result, to make it more useful after the fact...kinda making your UI's textbox a little silly.

---

If your project is set up for it, you can use Task Inheritance and modify task behavior that way. In theory you should be able to overwrite `apply` and `apply_async` to inject a task's ID.

```
import time

from celery import Task

 class NamedTask(Task):
    id_gen = lambda: int(time.time() * 1000)


    def _gen_task_id(self):
        return {
            'task_id': '%s-%s' % (
                self.name,
                self.id_gen())}

    def apply(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update(self._gen_task_id())
        return Task.apply(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def apply_async(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update(self._gen_task_id())
        return Task.apply_async(self, *args, **kwargs)



@task(base=NamedTask)
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Should make your Task ID look like: `project.tasks.add-15073315189870`

Comment: Hi I dont want to alter the task ID, that is fine, I was wondering if I can add another field to the model where I can give it a description and see it in the django_celery_resutls DB view?

Comment: @AlexW, your question should have been clear on that. Because now the meaning of the question itself changes. And your title clearly stated `set task id to something human readable?`.

Comment: apologies for the confusion, re reading this I can see how the question needs improvment

Answer (score 1):

Implement a *custom result backend* that overwrites `_store_result` to decide what is saved as result to the database.

Depending on which backend you're using find the related class in `celery.backends`.

This example extends the result for an *amqp* backend.

```
class UsefulInfoBackend(AMQPBackend):
    def store_result(self, task_id, result, state,
                     traceback=None, request=None, **kwargs):
        result = super(UsefulInfoBackend, self).store_result(task_id, result, state,
                     traceback=None, request=None, **kwargs)
        result['useful_info'] = 'Very Useful! :)' # determine the rules for extraneous information here contains. 
        return result
```

When initializing `Celery` pass your result backend class.

```
celery.Celery(backend=UsefulInfoBackend)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case , I tried the next line of code and it worked like charm

```
>>> my_celery_task.apply_async((2, 2), task_id='human-readable')
>>> result = AsyncResult(my_celery_task.task_id)
>>> result
human-readable
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
@app.task(name="periodic_test")
def test(a, b):
    return a+b
```

This may help to find the task status in the UI, but Celery always needs a unique id for each task execution.